# Moodle: Allowing dual authentication for same account (manual and oidc)

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, office365, moodle

Iam using Moodle 10+ and I have done a manual enrolment for an user and also try using 0365 integration (oidc ) for the same user. Integration is done successfully and also syncing as expected. Using Active Directory sync user is matched and 0365 record is created successfully.

Now the problem is that it appears that every user can have only one authentication enabled. I wish users can either use manual authentication or Oidc to log in to their account.

Anyone has successfully implemented two authentication for a same account?

It’s throwing error when logged in using oidc for a same user who’s auth field in mdl_usr is set to manual. If I change to oidc he can’t login using manual.

Is there any solution for this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one authentication method per user.

https://docs.moodle.org/311/en/Authentication_FAQ#Can_a_user_have_more_than_one_authentication_method.3F

With manual authentication, the password is stored in Moodle.

With OAuth2, the password is stored on the remote server.

So you can't mix them.